# Eclipse Maven Update similar by Jdeveloper

Tags: eclipse, oracle, maven, m2eclipse, jdeveloper

Is there a similar to eclipse maven update by Jdeveloper maven project?[image]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

What does this option do in Eclipse?
Is it just to synchronize the Maven POM with the project definition in Eclipse?
If that is the case this should be done automatically for you in JDeveloper 12.
Once you add a library to your JDev project it will show up in your POM.

Comment: In the theory yes. But some times this doesn't work properly. You must first remove the dependency block tag, save the pom, reopen it and paste it again. Some times this works on this way. Some days you must call maven goals clean, test/install before the jdeveloper loads the dependencies